# Python tkinter - Moving object in Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm just learning python and I wanted to create a small little game, where I can move an object to the left to the right, up and down...

```
import tkinter
canvas=tkinter.Canvas(width=800,height=600)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_text(400,200,text='Starlight',font='Arial 100 bold')
canvas.create_text(400,325,text='Press a button to start the game',font='Arial 20')

a=400
b=500


def start(coordinates):
    canvas.delete("all")
    canvas.create_rectangle(a-20,b,a+20,b-50)

def moveright(coordinates2):
    a=a+100
    b=b+0
    canvas.delete("all")
    canvas.create_rectangle(a-20,b,a+20,b-50)




canvas.bind('<Button-1>',start)
canvas.bind('<Button-3>',start)
canvas.bind_all('<Right>',moveright)
```

I just programmed the moving right part, however I got a problem, it doesnt sees that a is 400, but if i write it into the def then I can move it just once to the new position, then it stops there.....any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

When you change `a` and `b` in `moveright`, it becomes local, so the next time `moveright` is called, a and b don't exist anymore.

Without my re-writing a lot of your code, you could make a simple fix by declaring `a` and `b` as global in `moveright`, so they persist after `moveright` terminates:

```
def moveright(coordinates2):
    global a
    global b
    a=a+100
    b=b+0
    canvas.delete("all")
    canvas.create_rectangle(a-20,b,a+20,b-50)
```

Since `a` and `b` are now global, they persist after `moveright` terminates, and can be used by the next call to `moveright`.

Note: This isn't the best way your program could be written, just the simplest fix that also obviates the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix your issue with movenent you will need to use the `global` statement to let the function know the variables you are trying to work with are in the global namespace.

That said I would advocate for an OOP approach to avoid the use of global.

By building this into a class and using class attributes we can manage the movement without global. Additionally if we work with the event being passed to out class method we can use a single method to move in all 4 directions.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Example(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.canvas=tk.Canvas(self, width=800, height=600)
        self.canvas.create_text(400, 200, text='Starlight', font='Arial 20 bold')
        self.canvas.create_text(400, 325, text='Press a button to start the game', font='Arial 20')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.a=400
        self.b=500
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.start)
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-3>', self.start)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Left>', self.move_any)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Right>', self.move_any)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Up>', self.move_any)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Down>', self.move_any)

    def start(self, coordinates):
        self.canvas.delete("all")
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.a - 20, self.b, self.a + 20, self.b - 50)

    def move_any(self, event):
        self.canvas.delete("all")
        x = event.keysym
        if x == "Left":
            self.a -= 100
        if x == "Right":
            self.a += 100
        if x == "Up":
            self.b -= 100
        if x == "Down":
            self.b += 100 
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.a - 20, self.b, self.a + 20, self.b - 50)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Example().mainloop()
```